# Keep Divs on the same line when resizing responsively

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-images

I am having trouble figuring out how to keep my divs on the same line. I wanted all images to remain on the same line, scaling down/up in size as the screen adjusted without any overflow or horizontal scrolling. Each image is a link that javascript code will run to display hidden text.

Here is the site where the issue lies: [My website](http://debora.com.au/about)

I have created a jsfiddle for all my code: [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/3462/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabimg" onclick="openTab(event, 'Newborns')"> 
      <img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/revslider/food-carousel/muesli-e1478867936723.jpg" alt=""> 
    </a> 
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabimg" onclick="openTab(event, 'Children')"> 
      <img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/revslider/food-carousel/muesli-e1478867936723.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
   </li> 
   <li>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabimg" onclick="openTab(event, 'Families')"> 
      <img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/revslider/food-carousel/muesli-e1478867936723.jpg" alt=""> 
     </a>
   </li> 
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabimg" onclick="openTab(event, 'Lifestyle')"> 
      <img src="http://debora.com.au/wp-content/uploads/revslider/food-carousel/muesli-e1478867936723.jpg" alt=""> 
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div id="Newborns" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Newborns</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Children" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Children</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Families" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Families</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Lifestyle" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Lifestyle</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Style the list */
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {
    float: left;
}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/*style the images*/
.tabimg{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

I checked numerous questions on here and scoured W3schools but can't find a solution.

I believe I am doing something wrong with the container (sorry I am still a beginner).

Thank you,

Richard

Comment: What do you want to happen when the page gets smaller? Do you want the images to resize or do you want the page to get a scrollbar?

Comment: do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/3464/

Comment: @BSMP I edited my question, I did want the images to get smaller/resize (but I believe I'll need to implement media queries right?) I did not want any of the images to go off screen nor did I want any scrolling, lol if it's not too much to ask please.

Comment: @TommySchmidt Thank you for the jsfiddle, it was great in trying to troubleshoot my issue, it seems that the container is the issue? I can't figure out how to prevent the images from going off screen. I tried to implement position: absolute and position: fixed on container/images but the images seem to stack on top of each other in the z-axis (and it still goes off screen)

Comment: my fiddle was meant to wrap the images in a container with a scrollbar if they dont fit the page anymore. if you want the images to get smaller if they dont fit the page you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/3473/. This will adjust the width of the image based on the screen size. The height will be adjusted to fit the aspect ratio. I included some comments for the css.

Comment: Thank you Tommy for taking the time out to do all that. I finally got it working. Please post your link to the fiddle as an answer and I'll mark it.